# Asp.Net Transfer all Values Listbox to Another Page? (Response.Redirect)

Tags: asp.net, listbox

I have Problem with transfer all Data in Listbox from Page1 to Page2. Pleas, could me someone help me ?

Page1

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    int _count = Listbox1.Items.Count;
    if (_count != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _count; i++)
        {
            ListItem item = new ListItem();
            item.Text = Listbox1.Items[i].Text;
            item.Value = Listbox1.Items[i].Value;

            Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx?Listitems="+ item.Value);
```

Page 2

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i

    if (Request.QueryString["Listitems"] != null)
        ListItem1.Items.Add["Listitems"];
```

Sorry for easy question, but i have only Rookie in ASP.NET :(
Thank you

Comment: Use sessions to do this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [session variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), there is an example of how to pass lists using session variables [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/242826/how-to-pass-default1-aspx-listboxitems-to-default2) in "Solution 2".